# C# not running else statement bug or code error?

Tags: c#, if-statement

to make my issue easier I did the following: when tryparse works it shows true. When tryparse is false the program hangs and does nothing.

```
        string sal;
        sal = tbSalary.Text;
        float salary;
        //DateTime date;
        bool result;

        result = float.TryParse(sal, out salary);
        MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
```

Comment: Yeah, it's widely known that if/else doesn't work in c#.

Comment: looks like it involves some context here, such as other code you use in your project.

Comment: What environment are u using? Perhaps you're using a beta version of VS2013, which may be causing this. If you step through the code, where does it hang?

Comment: What line hangs when running this through the debugger?

Comment: @Rotem: IF if/else is not working in C#, what ELSE should i do? :)))

Comment: I am using VS ultimate 2012 update 4. So I have a form that displays information from a sql database, with a button called commit that when pressed updates the current record with the data changed. Everything works fine except if a user enters say 24b into the salary field instead of 24. If they enter just numbers it works fine but if they enter alpha, or nothing it should present a messagebox. The program runs, everything seem smooth but when invalid number is entered the program just hangs and seems to do nothing.

Comment: @user3001955, the code snippet you provided is out-of-context, as KingKing mentioned. For example, there is an `.EndEdit()` in one of the branches, which obviously has an associated `.BeginEdit()` before. Note that for the code as shown here, it appears that `.EndEdit()` is not called in all cases...

Comment: that is all of my code, I never used a .BeginEdit() I am relatively new to programming, have used an if else in this way before and didn't have any issues, so not sure maybe I need to recreate the project perhaps something got corrupt?

Comment: @user3001955, why do you use a source code snippet you do not understand? Are you forced to do that?

Comment: okay so I changed the code to the following and it will show true but when false it just hangs and I have to hit stop on debugger.          string sal;
            sal = tbSalary.Text;
            float salary;
            //DateTime date;
            bool result;

            result = float.TryParse(sal, out salary);
            MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());

Comment: Don't hit stop in the debugger. Hit **Pause** (it is called "Break all")! Then look at the call stack to see where your program hangs...

Comment: Do you mean (regarding your updated question), that the message box will not show when TryParse is false? The code as you show here doesn't hang...

Comment: @elgonzo yes when TryParse is false the messagebox will NOT show the program hangs.

Comment: @user3001955, please post your actual REAL code. The code snippet in your question DOES NOT hang. Don't expect people blind-guessing what your real code looks like...

Comment: so it has to be my project then, I am going to recreate this project and will post if it is fixed then. Thanks guys.

Comment: So the code does work however I discovered the issue is being caused because I have a databinding bound to the textbox I am tryparsing. Basically, the database will put a number in the textbox and I was trying to make it where a user could change the data and update it. Works fine but again, when trying to tryparse the information to make sure they typed a valid number the databinding causes the tryparse to fail. I will just have to find another way to code the textbox. Again, thank you everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The clauses

> sal != null

and

> tbStartDate.Text != null

are probably messing you up big time.

Comment: It was doing this before I had that line of code, I added that to see if it would do anything.

Comment: Well my C# is a bit rusty, but are you sure that is the right way to test for null values? You might have some tristate logic going on there.

Answer (score 0):

Convince yourself the basics of C# work as they should.  Comment out everything except the parsing code and MessageBoxes.  You don't need the null checks, or the extra string variable for the salary check:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        float salary;
        DateTime date;
        if (float.TryParse(tbSalary.Text, out salary))
        {
            if (DateTime.TryParse(tbStartDate.Text, out date))
            {
                // ... proper code to update your database but COMMENTED OUT ...
                MessageBox.Show("Changes Saved");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Date must be MM/DD/YY form");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Salary must be a numeric value");
        }
    }
```

This works as it should.  If the program still hangs then there is code elsewhere causing problems that you are not showing us.